# Google Map API issue : android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

When I am trying to use google map api for one of my android application, I always see this error. I am found many similar type of question, but none of the answers works for me.

Here is the error I see:

> Blockquote
>   08-06 19:31:47.606 2602-2602/com.example.ank.mymap E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                               Process: com.example.ank.mymap, PID: 2602
>                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ank.mymap/com.example.ank.mymap.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                                Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
>                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
>                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
>                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
>                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166)
>                                                                                   at com.example.ank.mymap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
>                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
>                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
>                                                                                Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
>                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
>                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
>                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
>                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
>                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166) 
>                                                                                   at com.example.ank.mymap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
>                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that  is in the  element of AndroidManifest.xml
>                                                                                   at maps.y.k.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                   at maps.v.c.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.b(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.newMapFragmentDelegate(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                   at vl.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:62)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
>                                                                                   at qle.newMapFragmentDelegate(:com.google.android.gms:179)
>                                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.newMapFragmentDelegate(:com.google.android.gms:101)
>                                                                                   at qld.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms:62)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
>                                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzc$zza$zza.zzag(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$zzb.zzbow(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onInflate(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                   at android.app.Fragment.onInflate(Fragment.java:1359)
>                                                                                   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2200)
>                                                                                   at android.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:98)
>                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5546)
>                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:36)
>                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:75)
>                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:754)
>                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
>                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
>                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
>                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166) 
>                                                                                   at com.example.ank.mymap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
>   Blockquote

## MainActivity.java

```
// all the import statements 

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;

 //public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    GoogleMap mMap;
    private  static final  int ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if(servicesOK()) {
            //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ready to map!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
    }
    public boolean servicesOK() {

        int isAvailable = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

        if (isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            return true;
        } else if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(isAvailable)) {
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(isAvailable, this, ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST);
            dialog.show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Can't connect to mapping service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

## activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.aveekadhya.mymap.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

## activity_map.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

## AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.aveekadhya.mymap">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCU9......" />

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</manifest>
```

The target SDK and min SDK is as follows:
 minSdkVersion 16
 targetSdkVersion 24

Not sure what I am doing wrong. Any suggestion is appreciated. I am running on emulatore based on Android Studio 2.1.2.

Comment: `java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found. Check that is in the element of AndroidManifest.xml at maps..` Are you sure you have included google maps api key in the manifest?

Comment: Yes it is present in AndroidManifest.xml file. Is there any way to check whether the key is valid?                                                                      <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCU9bl0HyIOV_btJyDtz6rKMwxM6rPX2ak" />

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

Comment: did you try to change android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" to android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" in activity_map.xml

Comment: Yes , I tried with modifying to "android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment".  But I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio reported the error :

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that
>    is in the  element of
>   AndroidManifest.xml

Thanks **much-overflow** to point it out.
The actual problem was I declared google map api key outside the  element of AndroidManifest.xml.
Once I cut-paste it within the  element, it works just fine.

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCU....." />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Thanks all of you for your time.